# how to perform a index search method

Tags: c++, visual-c++

im trying to perform an index search for string, im getting an error message: invalid conversion from const char* to int. can someone please explain what this means.

here is the code

```
#include <iostream>

#include<string>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;



void clist(char fn[],char ln[], int size);



char search_list(const char fn[],const char ln[], int size, string find);



int main(){

    string search;



    cout << "This program searches a list .\n";

const int total = 3;

char fn[total];
char ln[total];

clist(fn,ln, total);

cout << "Search contact:____  ";

cin >> search;

search_list(fn,ln, total, search);



  return 0;

}

void clist(char fn[],char ln[], int size){

    cout << "Enter " << size << " contact.\n";

    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
     cin >> fn[index] >> ln[index] ;

}
```

// somewhere in this block of code is giving me an error but i cant seem to figure it out, plz help and thanks
    char search_list(const char fn[], const char ln[],int size, char search){

```
    int index = 0;

    while ((fn[index] != search) && (index < size))

        index++;

    if (index == size)//if target is not in a.

        index = "";

    return index;

}
```

Comment: Too much code inside. Look closer at the error message you receive - it must contain code line number at which error is encountered.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling a function which takes arguments of type

```
const char[], const char[], int, char
```

with the arguments

```
const char[], const char[], int, string
```

You can see how the last ones don't match up.

Also, you're trying to assign a `char const[]` to an `int` with this line:

```
index = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (index == size)//if target is not in a.

    index = "";
```

Here is the error, your index is an integer, you can't set it to a char* type.